# Bash while read line loop does not print every line in condition

Tags: bash, awk

I have the following situation:

I have a text file I'm trying to loop so I can know if each line has a match with ".mp3" in this case which is this one:

```
12 Stones.mp3
randomfile.txt
Aclarion.mp3
ransomwebpage.html
Agents Of The Sun.mp3
randomvideo.mp4
```

So, I've written the following script to process it:

```
while read line || [ -n "$line" ]
do
varline=$(awk '/.mp3/{print "yes";next}{print "no"}')
echo $varline
if [ "$varline" == "yes" ]; then
        some-command
    else
         some-command
    fi
done < file.txt
```

The expected output would be:

```
yes
no
yes
no
yes
no
```

Instead, it seems misses the first line and I get the following:

```
no
yes
no
yes
no
```

Comment: Your `awk` command is consuming the entire input after the first call to `read`; your `while` only executes once.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You really don't need Awk for a simple pattern match if that's all you used it for.

```
while IFS= read -r line; do
    case $line in
     *.mp3) some-command;,
     *) some-other-command;;
    esac
done <file.txt
```

If you are using Awk anyway for other reasons, looping the lines in a shell loop is inefficient and very often an antipattern. This doesn't really fix that, but at least avoids executing a new Awk instance on every iteration:

```
awk '{ print ($0 ~ /\.mp3$/) ? "yes" : no" }' file.txt |
while IFS= read -r whether; do
    case $whether in
     'yes') some-command ;;
     'no') some-other-command;;
    esac
done
```

If you need the contents of `"$line"` too, printing that from Awk as well and reading two distinct variables is a trivial change.

I simplified the `read` expression on the assumption that you can make sure your input file is well-formed separately. If you can't do that, you need to put back the more-complex guard against a missing newline on the last line in the file.

Comment: Notice also the corrected regex, with a backslash before the dot and the `$` line-end anchor.

Comment: While I obviously agree with `looping the lines in a shell loop is inefficient and very often an antipattern` in general, in this case the awk preprocessing part isn't avoiding the shell loop and a case statement for every line so IMHO is not useful. Remember to use `while IFS=` by default on read loops.

Comment: @EdMorton Thanks; updated. The third option would be to execute commands with `system()` from within the Awk script but that's another can of worms I didn't want to open.

Answer (score 2):

Use `awk`

```
$ awk '{if ($0 ~ /mp3/) {print "yes"} else {print "no"}}' file.txt
yes
no
yes
no
yes
no
```

Or more concise:

```
$ awk '/mp3/{print "yes";next}{print "no"}' file.txt
$ awk '{print (/mp3/ ? "yes" : "no")}' file.txt
```

Comment: What would happen with a file named `mp3_list.html`? Perhaps anchoring the regex at the end and checking for an explicit extension would be prudent, e.g. `($0 ~ /[.]mp3$/)`.

Answer (score 2):

Have you forgot something?  Your `awk` has no explicit input, change to this instead:

```
while IFS= read -r read line || [ -n "$line" ]
do
varline=$(echo "$line" | awk '/.mp3/{print "yes";next}{print "no"}')
echo $varline
if [ "$varline" == "yes" ]; then
        some-command
    else
        some-other-command
    fi
done < file.txt
```

In this case, you might need to change to `/\.mp3$/` or `/\.mp3[[:space:]]*$/` for precise matching.
Because `.` will match any character, so for example `/.mp3/` will match `Exmp3but.mp4` too.
Update: changed `while read line` to `while IFS= read -r read line`, to keep each line's content intact when assigning to the variable.

And the `awk` part can be improved to:

```
awk '{print $0~/\.mp3$/ ? "yes":"no"}'
```

So with `awk` only, you can do it like this:

```
awk '{print $0~/\.mp3$/ ? "yes":"no"}' file.txt
```

Or if your purpose is just the commands in the if structure, you can just do this:

```
awk '/\.mp3$/{system("some-command");next}{system("some-other-command");}' file.txt
```

or this:

```
awk '{system($0~/\.mp3$/ ? "some-command" : "some-other-command")}' file.txt
```